# jQuery plugin: Parsing a JSONP feed using ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery and this is my first attempt at creating a plugin. The code below I've written to parse a JSONP feed from a search engine API (funnelback) using ajax() calls. The returned object is used to create a set of results, some pagination links, a facetted navigation etc, everything you'd expect from a basic search results UI.

I suspect there is a fair amount of redundant code, code that could be merged or performance hits written in so I'd appreciate your expert opinion as to what I could modify to improve these aspects.

I'd also appreciate any best practice advice I could incorporate to further develop my own skills and knowledge.

You'll notice there's a reference to the jQuery version used, this is because this plugin can be used with a range of CMS templates that have anything from jQuery 1.3.2 to 1.7 and beyond, so I need to cover the bases. (in reference to the on(), delegate() and live() methods)

```
(function($) {
$.fn.uclfunnelback = function(options) {
    // define the default values of parameters
    // these can be overwritten from the plugin call
    var defaults = {
        collection: 'enterprise-case-studies-demo',
        query: '!showmeall',
        categories: [{"facet_group_id": "discipline", "facet_group_title": "Discipline", "facet_items": {"mathematical-physical-sciences": "Mathematical & Physical Sciences", "arts-humanities": "Arts & Humanities", "engineering": "Engineering", "built-environment": "Built Environment", "social-historical-science": "Social & Historical Science", "life-medical-sciences": "Life & Medical Sciences", "laws": "Laws"}}, {"facet_group_id": "mechanisms", "facet_group_title": "Mechanisms", "facet_items": {"research-collaborations-studentships": "Research Collaborations Studentships", "student-engagement": "Student Engagement", "placements": "Placements", "business-support": "Business Support", "consultancy": "Consultancy", "partnerships": "Partnerships", "licenses": "Licenses", "spin-out": "Spin Out", "subsidiary": "Subsidiary"}}, {"facet_group_id": "grand_challenges", "facet_group_title": "Grand Challenges", "facet_items": {"sustainable-cities": "Sustainable Cities", "intercultural-interaction": "Intercultural Interaction", "global-health": "Global Health", "human-wellbeing": "Human Wellbeing"}}]
    };
    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    // Define the global vars
    var jq_version = $().jquery,
        facetsSelected = {},
        qs,
        facetqs,
        objid,
        categories = {},
        facetgroups,
        facetTotals = {},
        catArray = options.categories,
        catLen = catArray.length;
    // jq_version - The jquery version being used.
    // facetsSelected - The facets that are selected by the facetted navigation, used to generate the facetLabels
    // qs - The main query string passed to ajaxCall()
    // facetqs - The query string that is generated by the facetted navigation, used to perform the ajax call
    // objid - The main id of the container div into which everything is output
    // categories - The empty JavaScript object for all of the facet categories, used by facetLabels and checkBoxTotals
    // facetgroups - The collections of facets from each facet group
    // facetTotals - The JavaScript object for all the total articles matching each category, used by facettedNav and checkBoxTotals
    // catArray - Assign the user supplied list of categories to an Array, used by facettedNav & below
    // catLen - Predetermine the array length to speed up the for loop, used by facettedNav & below
    // Merge each of the category facets together into the JavaScript object 'categories'

    for (var i=0; i < catLen; i++) {
        facetgroups = catArray[i].facet_items;
        $.extend(categories, facetgroups);
    }

    Object.size = function(obj) {
        var size = 0, key;
        for (key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                size++;
            }
        }
        return size;
    };

    function AjaxTimer(status) {
        // A timer to record the funnelback json response time
        var aCounter = 0;
        var airSeconds = $('#air_seconds');
        var anInterval;
        if (status === "start") {
            anInterval = setInterval(function () {
                aCounter += 1;
                airSeconds.text(aCounter);
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            clearInterval(anInterval);
            anInterval = null;
        }
    }

    function showLoading() {
        // Display the AJAX loading icon & the timer if slow to load
        $('#awaiting_response').show();
        $('#fb-data').hide();
        $("#error").hide();
        AjaxTimer("start");
    }

    function ajaxError(request, type, errorThrown) {
        // Handle the AJAX load errors
        AjaxTimer("stop");
        $("#awaiting_response").hide();
        $('#fb-data').hide();
        $("#error").show();
        var message = "There was an error requesting the data.";
        switch (type) {
        case 'timeout':
            message += "The data took too long to retrieve.";
            break;
        case 'notmodified':
            message += "The request was not modified but was retrieved from the cache.";
            break;
        case 'parsererror':
            message += "The data was badly formatted.";
            break;
        default:
            message += "HTTP Error: (" + request.status + " " + request.statusText + ").";
        }
        message += "<br />";
        $("#error").append(message);
    }

    function paginationClicky(pageNo) {
        // Click function for the pagination buttons
        if ( facetqs ) {
            ajaxCall(pageNo, facetqs);
        } else {
            ajaxCall(pageNo, null);
        }
    }

    function bindPaginationEvent(pagclass, pageNo) {
        // Bind the pagination events, with modifications for older versions of jQuery 
        if (jq_version >= '1.7') {
            // As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. 
            $(objid).off('click', pagclass);
            $(objid).on('click', pagclass, function(e) {
                paginationClicky(pageNo);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        } else if ( jq_version >= '1.4.3' && jq_version < '1.7') {
            // Users of jQuery versions 1.4.3 to 1.7 should use .delegate() in preference to .live().
            $(objid).undelegate(pagclass, 'click');
            $(objid).delegate(pagclass, 'click', function(e){
                paginationClicky(pageNo);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        } else {
            // Users of jquery 1.3.2 have no choice but to use live()
            $(pagclass).die('click');
            $(pagclass).live('click', function(e){
                paginationClicky(pageNo);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }

    function checkboxToggle(checkbox) {
        // Toggle function for the checkboxes
        if (checkbox.attr("checked")) {
            facetsSelected[checkbox.attr('value')] = checkbox.val();
        } else {
            delete facetsSelected[checkbox.attr('value')];
        }
        facetFormSubmit();
    }

    function bindCheckboxToggle(selectorStr) {
        // Bind the checkbox toggle events, with modifications for older versions of jQuery
        var checkboxSelector = 'input:checkbox.' + selectorStr;
        if (jq_version >= '1.7') {
            // As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. 
            $(objid).off('change', checkboxSelector);
            $(objid).on('change', checkboxSelector, function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                checkboxToggle($this);
            });
        } else if ( jq_version >= '1.4.3' && jq_version < '1.7') {
            // Users of jQuery versions 1.4.3 to 1.7 should use .delegate() in preference to .live().
            $(objid).undelegate(checkboxSelector, 'change');
            $(objid).delegate(checkboxSelector, 'change', function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                checkboxToggle($this);
            });
        } else {
            // Users of jquery 1.3.2 have no choice but to use live()
            $(checkboxSelector).die('change');
            $(checkboxSelector).live('change', function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                checkboxToggle($this);
            });
        }
    }

    function bindFacetLabel(facetid) {
        // Bind the facetLables click events, with modifications for older versions of jQuery
        var facetselector = 'a.' + facetid;
        var checkboxSelector = 'input:checkbox.' + facetid;
        if (jq_version >= '1.7') {
            // As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. 
            $(objid).off('click', facetselector);
            $(objid).on('click', facetselector, function(e) {
                delete facetsSelected[facetid];
                $(checkboxSelector).removeAttr('checked');
                e.preventDefault();
                facetFormSubmit();
            });
        } else if ( jq_version >= '1.4.3' && jq_version < '1.7') {
            // Users of jQuery versions 1.4.3 to 1.7 should use .delegate() in preference to .live().
            $(objid).undelegate(facetselector, 'click');
            $(objid).delegate(facetselector, 'click', function(e){
                delete facetsSelected[facetid];
                $(checkboxSelector).removeAttr('checked');
                e.preventDefault();
                facetFormSubmit();
            });
        } else {
            // Users of jquery 1.3.2 have no choice but to use live()
            $(facetselector).die('click');
            $(facetselector).live('click', function(e){
                delete facetsSelected[facetid];
                $(checkboxSelector).removeAttr('checked');
                e.preventDefault();
                facetFormSubmit();
            });
        }
    }

    function facetLabels(totalMatching) {
        // Generate the facet labels
        var freeText = $("#fbquery").val();
        var res, csText;
        var facetLen = Object.size(facetsSelected);
        var facetoutput = "";
        if (totalMatching === 1) {
            res = " result";
            csText  = " Item";
        } else {
            res = " results";
            csText  = " Items";
        }
        if (facetLen > 0) {
            facetoutput += "<div id='pillboxes'><h3>Active Filters</h3><ul>";
            for (var prop in facetsSelected) {
                if (facetsSelected.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    facetoutput += "<li><a class='"+ prop +"' href='#'>" + categories[prop] + "</a></li>";
                    bindFacetLabel(prop);
                }
            }
            facetoutput += "</ul><div style='clear:both;'></div></div>";
        }
        facetoutput += "<h3><span class='resultCount'>" + totalMatching + "</span> ";
        if (facetLen === 0 && !freeText) {
            facetoutput += csText + " found";
        } else if (facetLen === 0 && freeText) {
            facetoutput += res + " matched your search for <span class='searchTerm'>'" + freeText + "'</span>";
        } else {
            var facetCounter = 0;
            for (var facet in facetsSelected) {
                if (facetsSelected.hasOwnProperty(facet)) {
                    facetCounter++;
                    var facetTitle = categories[facetsSelected[facet]];
                    if (facetCounter === 1) {
                        facetoutput += res + " matched your search for <span class='searchTerm'>" + facetTitle + "</span>";
                    } else if (facetCounter === facetLen - 1) {
                        facetoutput += ", <span class='searchTerm'>" + facetTitle + "</span>";
                    } else {
                        if (!freeText) {
                            facetoutput += " and <span class='searchTerm'>" + facetTitle + "</span>";
                        } else {
                            facetoutput += ", <span class='searchTerm'>" + facetTitle + "</span>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (freeText) {
                facetoutput += " and <span class='searchTerm'>'" + freeText + "'</span>";
            }
        }
        facetoutput += "</h3>";
        $('.resultcount').html(facetoutput);
    }

    function searchResults(currStart, data) {
        // Generate the basic search results
        // the results are derived from the json feed (data).
        var i,
            res_output = "",
            searchItems = data.response.resultPacket.results;
        res_output += "<ol start='" + currStart + "'><br />";
        for (i in searchItems) {
            if (searchItems.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                res_output += "<li><h4><a href='" + searchItems[i].liveUrl + "'>" + searchItems[i].title + "</a></h4><p>" + searchItems[i].summary+"</p></li>";
            }
        }
        res_output += '</ol>';
        $(objid).html(res_output);
    }

    function pagination (currStart, numPages, currPage, numRanks, nextStart, prevStart) {
        // Generate the pagination links      
        var linksString = "<p class='fb-page-nav'>";
        var page_class;
        if (currStart > 1) {
            // previous links
            linksString += "<a class='fb-previous-result-page' href='#'>Prev 10</a> ";
            bindPaginationEvent('.fb-previous-result-page',prevStart);
        }
        var startRank = 1;
        if (numPages > 1) {
            for (i=0; i<numPages; i++){
                if (i !== currPage) {
                    // if the page is not the current page
                    page_class = "fb-result-page"+ (1+i);
                    linksString += "&nbsp;<a class='" + page_class + "'  href='#'>" + (1+i) +"</a> ";
                    bindPaginationEvent('a.' + page_class,startRank);
                } else {
                    // if the page is the current page
                    linksString += "&nbsp;<a class='fb-current-result-page' href='#'>" + (1+i) + "</a>";
                    bindPaginationEvent('.fb-current-result-page',startRank);
                }
                startRank += numRanks;
            }
        }
        if (nextStart) {
            // next links
            linksString += "&nbsp; <a class='fb-next-result-page fb-page-nav' href='#'>Next 10</a>";
            bindPaginationEvent('.fb-next-result-page',nextStart);
        }
        linksString += "</p>";
        $('.pagination').html(linksString);
    }

    function contains(array, value) {
        // function to determine if a value is contained within an array
        // Faster than inArray() and indexOf() and..
        // supported by *all* browsers unlike indexOf()
        var index = -1,
        length = array.length;

        while (++index < length) {
            if (array[index] === value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function checkboxTotals(facetData) {
        // Calculate the facet checkbox totals
        var temp, tally, isMultiFacetted;
        // iterate the 'categories' json array
        for (var facet in categories) {
            if (categories.hasOwnProperty(facet)) {
                facetTotals[facet] = 0;
            }
        }
        // iterate the rmcs json object {}
        for (var i in facetData) {
            if (facetData.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                temp = i.slice(2,i.length);
                tally = facetData[i];
                isMultiFacetted = contains(temp, ',');

                if (isMultiFacetted) {
                    // if temp is more than one item
                    // split it and make an array
                    var token = temp.split(",");
                    var tokenlen = token.length;
                    // iterate the array 
                    // and compare the item (j) found with each item in categories object
                    // if j and c same then increment facetTotals for the appropriate facet
                    for (var j=0; j<tokenlen; j++) {
                        for (var c in categories) {
                            if (categories.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
                                if (token[j] === c) {
                                    facetTotals[c] += tally;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    facetTotals[temp] += tally;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function resetForm() {
        // Event handler to reset the form back to the defaults
        $('.reset-button').die('click');
        $('.reset-button').live('click', function(){
            facetsSelected = {};
            ajaxCall(null, null);
        });
    }

    function facettedNav() {
        // Generate the facetted Navigation
        var facetoutput = '';
        // catArray & catLen are global vars.
        for (var i = 0; i < catLen; i++) {
            // Generate the facet titles from the json objects in catArray
            facetoutput += '<h3>' + catArray[i].facet_group_title + '</h3>\n<ul>';
            // iterate the json array of the facet iems to generate the checkboxes
            var itemsObj = catArray[i].facet_items;
            var groupID = catArray[i].facet_group_id;
            var metadataClass = 'meta_' + groupID.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + '_sand';
            for (var key in itemsObj) {
                if (itemsObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    // if there total no of results for any given facet is greater than 0, display the facet checkbox
                    if (facetTotals[key] > 0) {
                        if (facetsSelected.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            facetoutput += '<li id="' + key + '" style="opacity: 1;"><label><input type="checkbox" class="' + key + '" name="' + metadataClass  + '" value="' + key + '" checked>' + itemsObj[key] + ' <span class="count">(' + facetTotals[key] + ')</span> </label></li>';
                        } else {
                            facetoutput += '<li id="' + key + '" style="opacity: 1;"><label><input type="checkbox" class="' + key + '" name="' + metadataClass  + '" value="' + key + '">' + itemsObj[key] + ' <span class="count">(' + facetTotals[key] + ')</span> </label></li>';
                        }
                        bindCheckboxToggle(key);
                    } else {
                        // else show the facet checkbox but disable it and lowever the labels opacity
                        facetoutput += '<li id="' + key + '" style="opacity: 0.5;"><label><input type="checkbox" class="' + key + '" disabled="disabled" name="' + metadataClass  + '" value="' + key + '">' + itemsObj[key] + ' <span class="count">(' + facetTotals[key] + ')</span> </label></li>';
                    }
                }
            }
            facetoutput += '</ul>';
        }
        // Add the reset button
        facetoutput += '<input class="reset-button" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">';
        resetForm();
        // Insert the generated output to the appropriate div
        $('.facetted-nav').html(facetoutput);
    }

    function facetFormSubmit() {
        // Generte the new query string everytime the form is submit
        facetqs = $('#facetsearch').serialize();
        ajaxCall(null, facetqs);
    }

    function parseResults(data){
        // Parse the json feed and render the results
        // 1st stop the timer
        AjaxTimer("stop");
        // & show or hide the appropriate divs
        $('#awaiting_response').hide();
        $('#fb-data').show();
        $("#error").hide();
        // collate the data from the json feed
        var totalMatching = data.response.resultPacket.resultsSummary.totalMatching;
        var numRanks = data.response.resultPacket.resultsSummary.numRanks;
        var currStart = data.response.resultPacket.resultsSummary.currStart;
        var prevStart = data.response.resultPacket.resultsSummary.prevStart;
        var nextStart = data.response.resultPacket.resultsSummary.nextStart;
        var numPages = Math.ceil(totalMatching/numRanks);
        var currPage = Math.floor(currStart/numRanks);
        var facetData = data.response.resultPacket.rmcs;
        // Calculate the checkbox totals
        checkboxTotals(facetData);
        // Display the facetted navigation beneath the search
        facettedNav();
        // Display the heading and the filtering info
        facetLabels(totalMatching);
        // Display the search results in the appropriate div
        searchResults(currStart, data);
        // Display the pagination
        pagination(currStart, numPages, currPage, numRanks, nextStart, prevStart);

        // Bind an event handler to the form "submit" JavaScript event
        $('#facetsearch').submit(function(e) {
            facetFormSubmit();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }

    function ajaxCall(startRank, facetqs) {
        // This is the universal ajax call method
        // Reset the query string to '' first
        qs = '';
        // Build the query string for the ajax() call
        // Generate the 'query' element so that if facets are checked they concatenate
        if (facetqs && facetqs !== 'query=') {
            // Trim 'query=' off the beginning of facetqs
            var trimmedFacetqs = facetqs.substring(6);
            qs += '&query=' + trimmedFacetqs;
        } else {
            // If no facets checked, set the default 'query' element to options.query
            qs += '&query=' + options.query;
        }
        // Append the collection
        qs += '&collection=' + options.collection;
        // And append the startRank, if there is one
        if (startRank) {
            qs += '&start_rank=' + startRank;
        }
        // set the base funnelback url
        var baseurl = 'http://funnelback-uat.ucl.ac.uk/s/search.json?callback=?';
        // var testingurl = 'http://localhost:8217/silva/default-funnelback-search/search.json';
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            data: qs,
            url: baseurl,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            // url: testingurl,
            // dataType: "json", // Test dataType
            beforeSend: showLoading,
            timeout: 5000,
            error: ajaxError,
            scriptCharset: "utf-8",
            success: function (json) {
                parseResults(json);
            }
        });
    }

    // Initiate the plugin
    return this.each(function() {
        // set some variables
        var obj = $(this);
        objid = "#" + obj.attr('id');
        // perform the inital ajaxCall
        ajaxCall(null, null);
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

I appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1):

Johntyb, the main problem you will have is with all those vars defined in the `$.fn.uclfunnelback` namespace; `options`, `defaults`, `facetsSelected`, etc.

Any vars defined there belong to the plugin itself, not to each instance of the plugin, therefore different instances of the plugin will crosstalk.

The plugin pattern explained/advocated [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) shows how this can be overcome.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I'll have a read of that page. Much appreciated.